# How can I debug Trigger.io in iOS?

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I cannot get Catalyst debugger to recognize the application after it's been started. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The hash is exactly the same in the URL as it is in the app's head block, and yet the "Targets" still show "none." What could be going wrong?

Comment: Am not sure but do you have an internet connection on your device?

Comment: Yes, but it was not accepting connections. It turned out to be that iPhone simulator's plist file had to be modified to accept external domains. I found that out when I had the same problem with Phonegap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be that iPhone simulator's plist file had to be modified to accept external domains. I found that out when I had the same problem with Phonegap.

Comment: Hi, I'm part of the Trigger team - we've not heard anything similar before and our simulators can be debugged with no modification: can you tell me what simulator and XCode version you're using, and give some more detail about your workaround? Would be really helpful!

Comment: Here is the screencap of the configuration setting I had to tweak in order to make it work. http://cl.ly/HURJ  It's a file called Cordova.plist, in Phonegap, under Supporting Files. Xcode version 4.3.2.